# Python, Cifra de César, Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Olá, gostaria de pedir algumas dicas para melhorar o código, principalmente na função 'geraMsgTraduzida', para deixar o código mais bonito se for possível.

```
def recebeModo():
    """
    Função que pergunta se o usuário quer criptografar ou
    decriptografar e garante que uma entrada válida foi recebida
    """

    while True:
        option = input("Deseja criptografar ou descriptografar? ")
        option = option.lower()
        if option == 'c' or option == 'criptografar' or option == 'descriptografar' or option == 'd':
            return option
        print("Entrada inválida. Escolha entre ('criptografar', 'c') ou ('descriptografar', 'd')")


def recebeChave():
    """
    Função que pede o valor da chave para o usuário
    e devolve a chave caso o valor desta esteja adequado
    """
    while True:
        chave = int(input("Digite o valor da chave: "))
        if 1 <= chave <= 26:
            break
        print("Entrada inválida")

    return chave

def geraMsgTraduzida(modo, mensagem, chave):
    """
    Traduz a mensagem do usuário de modo conveniente
    """
    cripto = ''

    if modo == 'c' or modo == 'criptografar':
        for i in mensagem:
            if 'A' <= i <= 'Z':
                if ord(i) + chave > ord('Z'):
                    cripto += chr((ord('A') + chave - (ord('Z')+1 - ord(i))))
                else:
                    cripto += chr(ord(i) + chave)


            elif 'a' <= i <= 'z':
                if ord(i) + chave > ord('z'):
                    cripto += chr((ord('a') + chave - (ord('z')+1 - ord(i))))
                else:
                    cripto += chr(ord(i) + chave)
            else:
                cripto += i

    elif modo == 'd' or modo == 'descriptografar':
        for i in mensagem:
            if 'A' <= i <= 'Z':
                if ord(i) - chave < ord('A'):
                    cripto += chr(ord('Z') - (chave - (ord(i)+1 - ord('A'))))

                else:
                    cripto += chr(ord(i) - chave)


            elif 'a' <= i <= 'z':
                if ord(i) - chave < ord('a'):
                    cripto += chr(ord('z') - (chave - (ord(i)+1 - ord('a'))))
                else:
                    cripto += chr(ord(i) - chave)
            else:
                cripto += i 

    return cripto

def main():
    """
    Função principal do programa
    """

    modo = recebeModo()
    chave = recebeChave()
    mensagem = input("Digite a mensagem: ")
    print(geraMsgTraduzida(modo, mensagem, chave))

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas pequenas sugestões no teu código:

- alterei as repetições para não usar white True (fiz duas possibilidades, função recebeModo e recebeChave)
- modularizei o teu método geraMsgTraduzida, criando dois métodos: decripta e encripta.

  def recebeModo():
          option = input("Deseja criptografar ou descriptografar? ").lower()
          while option != 'c' and option != 'criptografar' and option != 'descriptografar' and option != 'd':
              print("ERRO: Entrada inválida. Escolha entre ('criptografar', 'c') ou ('descriptografar', 'd')")
              option = input("Deseja criptografar ou descriptografar? ").lower()
  return option

  ```
  def recebeChave():
      chave = 1
      entrada_valida = False
      while not entrada_valida:
          chave = int(input("Digite o valor da chave: "))
          if 1 <= chave <= 26:
              entrada_valida = True
          else:
              print("ERRO: Entrada inválida para a chave (1 a 26)")
      return chave


  def encripta(modo, mensagem, chave):
      cripto = ''
      for i in mensagem:
          if 'A' <= i <= 'Z':
              if ord(i) + chave > ord('Z'):
                  cripto += chr((ord('A') + chave - (ord('Z') + 1 - ord(i))))
              else:
                  cripto += chr(ord(i) + chave)
          elif 'a' <= i <= 'z':
              if ord(i) + chave > ord('z'):
                  cripto += chr((ord('a') + chave - (ord('z') + 1 - ord(i))))
              else:
                  cripto += chr(ord(i) + chave)
          else:
              cripto += i
      return cripto


  def decripta(modo, mensagem, chave):
      cripto = ''
      for i in mensagem:
          if 'A' <= i <= 'Z':
              if ord(i) - chave < ord('A'):
                  cripto += chr(ord('Z') - (chave - (ord(i) + 1 - ord('A'))))
              else:
                  cripto += chr(ord(i) - chave)
          elif 'a' <= i <= 'z':
              if ord(i) - chave < ord('a'):
                  cripto += chr(ord('z') - (chave - (ord(i) + 1 - ord('a'))))
              else:
                  cripto += chr(ord(i) - chave)
          else:
              cripto += i
      return cripto


  def geraMsgTraduzida(modo, mensagem, chave):
      nova_mensagem = ''
      if modo == 'c' or modo == 'criptografar':
          nova_mensagem = encripta(modo, mensagem, chave)
      elif modo == 'd' or modo == 'descriptografar':
          nova_mensagem = decripta(modo, mensagem, chave)
      return nova_mensagem


  def main():
      modo = recebeModo()
      chave = recebeChave()
      mensagem = input("Digite a mensagem: ")
      print(geraMsgTraduzida(modo, mensagem, chave))


  main()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

def cifraDeCesar(chave,arq):

```
#codificação das eltras minúsculas
alfaLow = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz'
quebraLow = alfaLow.partition(alfaLow[:chave])
tradLow = quebraLow[2]+quebraLow[1]

#codificação das eltras maiúsculas
alfaUp = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXZ'
quebraUp = alfaUp.partition(alfaUp[:chave])
tradUp = quebraUp[2]+quebraUp[1]

trad = str.maketrans(alfaLow+alfaUp,tradLow+tradUp)

arquivo = open(arq,'r')
return arquivo.read().translate(trad)
arquivo.close()
```

print(cifraDeCesar(3,'clear.txt'))